# Template disambiguator for dependent names

Tags: c++

I encountered the following problem by compiling the following example:

```
template <int N>
class Matrix {
public:
    template <int Idx>
    int head() {
        return Idx;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Test {
    static constexpr int RayDim = 3;
public:
    int func() const {
        Matrix<RayDim> yF;
        return yF.head<1>();
        //        ^ is template keyword required here?
    }
};

struct Empty {};

void test() {
    Test<Empty> t;
}
```

Link to Compiler Explorer:
https://godbolt.org/z/js4XaP

The code compiles with GCC 9.2 and MSVC 19.22 but not with clang 9.0.0. Clang states that a template keyword is required. If `static constexpr int RayDim = 3;` is moved into `int func() const` clang accepts it.

As stated as a comment in the code block, is the template keyword required for `yF.head<1>()`?

Comment: I think you may be running into a clang-specific implementation issue where matching template types to parameters isn't fully implemented yet: https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#p0522

Comment: I think `Matrix<RayDim>` is not a dependent type and so the keyword is not required. I may have time for an answer later.

Comment: @EddyLuten P0522 is about template template parameters, and there aren't any in this example.

Comment: A simplified example that seems to be related: https://godbolt.org/z/KpXpYs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `template` keyword should not be required here, so clang is incorrect to reject the program.

All C++ Standard section and paragraph numbers and quotes below are the same for C++17 draft N4659 and the current linked C++20 draft.

The requirement for `template` after a `.` or `->` or `::` token when naming a member template is in [[temp.names]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.names#4). The paragraph first lists cases where the keyword is not allowed, then cases where it is optional and doesn't make a difference, then:

> In all other contexts, when naming a template specialization of a member of an unknown specialization ([[temp.dep.type]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.dep.type)), the member template name shall be prefixed by the keyword `template`.

A "member of an unknown specialization" is a member of a dependent type which is not "the current instantiation". So the question is whether `Matrix<RayDim>` is a dependent type. For that, we look at [temp.dep.type]/9:

> A type is dependent if it is
>
> - a template parameter,
> - a member of an unknown specialization,
> - a nested class or enumeration that is a dependent member of the current instantiation,
> - a cv-qualified type where the cv-unqualified type is dependent,
> - a compound type constructed from any dependent type,
> - an array type whose element type is dependent or whose bound (if any) is value-dependent,
> - a function type whose exception specification is value-dependent,
> - a *simple-template-id* in which either the template name is a template parameter or any of the template arguments is a dependent type or an expression that is type-dependent or value-dependent or is a pack expansion, or
> - denoted by `decltype(`*expression*`)`, where *expression* is type-dependent.

`Matrix<RayDim>` is clearly not a template parameter, any kind of member, cv-qualified, an array type, a function type, or specified by `decltype`. It is a compound type, but it uses only a template-name and an expression, so is not constructed from any other type.

That leaves the *simple-template-id* case. The template name `Matrix` is not a template parameter. The template argument `RayDim` is an expression, so now to see if it is type-dependent or value-dependent.

"Type-dependent" is defined in [[temp.dep.expr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.dep.expr). Only paragraph 3 can apply to a lone identifier like `RayDim`:

> An *id-expression* is type-dependent if it contains
>
> - an *identifier* associated by name lookup with one or more declarations declared with a dependent type,
> - an *identifier* associated by name lookup with a non-type *template-parameter* declared with a type that contains a placeholder type,
> - an *identifier* associated by name lookup with a variable declared with a type that contains a placeholder type ([dcl.spec.auto]) where the initializer is type-dependent,
> - an *identifier* associated by name lookup with one or more declarations of member functions of the current instantiation declared with a return type that contains a placeholder type,
> - an *identifier* associated by name lookup with a structured binding declaration whose *brace-or-equal-initializer* is type-dependent,
> - the identifier `__func__` ([dcl.fct.def.general]), where any enclosing function is a template, a member of a class template, or a generic lambda,
> - a *template-id* that is dependent,
> - a *conversion-function-id* that specifies a dependent type, or
> - a *nested-name-specifier* or a *qualified-id* that names a member of an unknown specialization;
>
> or if it names a dependent member of the current instantiation that is a static data member of type "array of unknown bound of `T`" for some `T` ([temp.static]).

`RayDim` certainly does not contain any `__func__`, *template-id*, *conversion-function-id*, *nested-name-specifier*, or *qualified-id*. Name lookup finds the class template's static member declaration. That declaration of `RayDim` is certainly not a *template-parameter*, a member function, or a structured binding declaration, and its type `const int` is certainly not a dependent type or array type and does not contain a placeholder type. So `RayDim` is not type-dependent.

"Value-dependent" is defined in [[temp.dep.constexpr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.dep.constexpr). The only cases that can apply to a lone identifier like `RayDim` are in paragraph 2:

> An *id-expression* is value-dependent if:
>
> - it is type-dependent,
> - it is the name of a non-type template parameter,
> - it names a static data member that is a dependent member of the current instantiation and is not initialized in a *member-declarator*,
> - it names a static member function that is a dependent member of the current instantiation, or
> - it is a constant with literal type and is initialized with an expression that is value-dependent.

From above, `RayDim` is not type-dependent. It is certainly not a template parameter or a member function. It is a static data member and dependent member of the current instantiation, but it is initialized in the *member-declarator*. That is, the "`= 3`" appears inside the class definition, not in a separate member definition. It is a constant with literal type, but its initializer `3` is not value-dependent.

So `RayDim` is not value-dependent or type-dependent. Therefore `Matrix<RayDim>` is not a dependent type, `yF.head` is not a member of an unknown instantiation, and the `template` keyword before `head` is optional, not required. (It is permitted since it's not in a "type-only context" and `head` does in fact name a member template.)

Answer (score 0):

## Disclaimer

*this is not an answer, but rather a long comment*

*My [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) skills are too low to fully understand the standard but here are a few things I discovered from experimenting with the code. Everything that follows is based on my (far from perfect) understanding of the matter and probably needs some reviews.*

## Investigation

First off, I went to a fully defined standard version (C++17) so we operate on a well defined implementation.

Looking at [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/jDfQFv) it seems like MSVC still has some problems (with its lookup, I guess?) when it comes to template instantiation and redefinition. I wouldn't trust MSVC that much in our scenario.

That beeing said, lets think about why we could need the `template` keyword at

```
return yF.template head<1>();
```

### Dependent names

Sometimes, inside templates, we have to help the compiler decide whether a *name* refers to

1. a value `int T::x = 0`,
2. a type `struct T::x {};`, or
3. a template `template <typename U> T::foo<U>();`

If we refer to a value, we do nothing. If we refer to a type, we have to use `typename`. And if we refer to a template we use `template`. More on that subject can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613132/6205379).

I don't understand the standard specification when it comes to the actual definition of a *dependent name* but here are some observations.

### Observations

Lets take a look at the reference code

```
template <int N>
struct Matrix 
{
    template <int Idx>
    int head() { return Idx; }
};
 

template <typename T>
struct Test 
{    
    static constexpr int RayDim = 3;

    int func() const 
    {
        Matrix<RayDim> yF;
        return yF.head<1>(); // clang complains, gcc and msvc are ok
    }
};


struct Empty {};

int test() 
{
    Test<Empty> t;
    return t.func();
}
```

Usually `RayDim` should be a dependent name (because it's inside the template `Test`) which would cause `Matrix<RayDim>` to be a dependent name aswell. For now, lets assume that `Matrix<RayDim>` actually is a dependent name. This makes `Matrix<RayDim>::head` a dependent name aswell. Since `Matrix<RayDim>::head` is a templated function it is a template in itself and the rules of dependent names from above apply, requiring us to use the `template` keyword. This is what clang is complaining about.

However, since `RayDim` is defined inside `Test` and `func` is also defined inside the same template and not a templated function in itself, I don't think `RayDim` actually is a dependent name in the context of `func`. Furthermore, `RayDim` doesn't rely on the template arguments of `Test`. In this case, `Matrix<RayDim>` and `Matrix<RayDim>::head` respectively, would become non-dependent names, which allows us to omit the `template` keyword. This is why gcc (and msvc) compile.

If we were to template `RayDim` aswell, like [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Tp3yWu)

```
template <typename>
static constexpr int RayDim = 3;
```

gcc would treat it as a dependent name aswell (which is correct, since there might be a template specialization later so we don't know at that point). Meanwhile, msvc happily accepts everything we throw at it.

## Conclusion

It seems like it's boiling down to whether `RayDim` is a dependent name in the context of `Test<T>::func` or not. Clang thinks it is, gcc doesn't. From some more test it looks like msvc sides with clang on this one. But it's also kinda doing it's own thing, so who knows?

I would side with gcc here as I see no possible way of `RayDim` becoming dependent at the point where `func` is instantiated.